# Google Sheets, IFS with a nested COUNTIF function

Tags: google-sheets

On Google Sheets I am trying to write this formula:

```
=ifs(F39>0,"1",(F1=((D63*12)+(countif(D63:E63)))),0)
```

I get a result of N/A. How do I properly include a COUNTIF function here?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.  Use **Insert > Note** to describe what you want in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

The formula errors out because `countif()` requires two parameters — the *range* to test, such as the `D63:E63` your formula uses, and the *condition* to test against. The condition bit is missing in the formula. A condition looks like `42`, meaning "equal to 42" or `"> 42"`, meaning "greater than 42", or `"<=" & G63`, meaning "less than or equal to the value in cell `G63`". Note the use of quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

```
0=ifs(F39>0,"1",(F1=((D63*12)+(countif(D63:E63,true)))),0)
```

Yes adding a second criterion fixed the error as already mentioned. I wanted to suggest that while you are working  on a formula if you press f9 to enable the help features then you can press CTRL+SPACE and it will describe a bit about what each value is required and where.